# Convert a VBS script to PHP

Tags: php, xml, vbscript

I have been given an example piece of code from a company I'm dealing with for how to post XML data to a URL then read the response. Unfortunately for me this in VBS which I don't have a good working knowledge of:

This is the section of code that I'm interested in. This should pass over the XML file that was read in to oXML then post it and read the response:

```
set oHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
oHTTP.open "POST", "http://www.ophub.net/opxml/response.asp", false,00092,QW 'file url - with dealers Account number, Password
oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sRequest)
oHTTP.send oXML
```

From what I understand of this in PHP this can be done with cUrl and I have come up with the following from bits that I have read online but this doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form- urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.ophub.net/opxml/response.asp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "00092:QW");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "XML=" . $xml);
$content=curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;
```

I'm sure I can't be far off what I need but I can't seem to get there so any hep would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post fields just set the xml no need to set `xml=`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
```

you also need return transfer true

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

Comment: And your edit about return transfer was the last bit!  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like that is *precisely* what you need. It seems to be an exact translation.

The only two potential issues that I can see are:

- You PHP code seems to have a space in the middle of the `Content-Type` header value, this will most likely break things
- You will, if you haven't already done so, need to URL encode the `$xml` data before sending it as part of a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` message (clue's in the type name :-P), which you can do with [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode).

It might be a good idea to build the body data as a string and echo it out, to ensure that the data is correct:

```
echo 'XML=' . urlencode($xml);
```

For the record wrapping XML messages in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is a horrible way to do things. But I've come across more than one API that does it, so I'm going to assume that your code is correct in this regard for the API you are trying to consume.

Comment: It's not exact translation there is no post var named `xml` in the original code,

Comment: @DevZer0 I'm assuming that element of it is handled by `oXML` in the original code, although that may not be the case. The `Content-Type` header indicated that this may be correct - which is why I suggest echoing out the body string to verify that the data is what the OP expects it to be.